# Loop and verify all elements' values

Tags: javascript

When I want to detect if **one** element has a specific value, I do it like this:

```
For ( var i = 0 ; i < nOccCount ; i++ ) {  
    var V =  i; 
    if (V == 'X') { break; }
}
```

Now I want to verify if **all** elements `(i = 0; i < nOccCountare; i++)` are equal to `'X'`.

How can I do that?

Thank you.

Comment: Look for an element that's `!=`

Comment: `var allEqualToX = array.every(e => e === "X")`

Comment: `var V =  i;` that makes V an integer...

Comment: Thanks all (this code is for indication only)

Comment: @ele, you can move that to an answer

Comment: @mrid answer posted!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) for doing that.

```
let allEqualToX = array.every(e => e === "X")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do it (for arrays you can see Ele's suggestion in the comments).

For the general idea you presented in the question, you just need to add a boolean variable and change your condition to search for a not equal element like this:

```
var allEqual = true;
for (var i = 0; i < nOccCount; i++) {  
    var v = i; 
    if (v != 'X') { 
        allEqual = false;
        break; 
    }
}
```

Because of the change `!=` in the condition, `allEqual` will be false if one or more elements are not equal to the value you are comparing to.

Answer (score 0):

So i change the code as you need, 
Created one array:

`var arr = [];`
arr variable value is:

`(7) ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]`

created one variable to track, is any value not matched with desired character:
`var allSame = true;`

one for loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(arr[i] != 'x'){
        allsame = false
    }
}
```

```js
var allSame = true;
var arr = ["x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x", "x"]
 for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if(arr[i] != 'x'){
            allsame = false
        }
    }
console.log(allSame);
alert("Are all value same :" + allSame);
```